# C++ перегрузка оператора = для объекта с shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Создал класс, который реализует массив на shared_ptr. Хочу перегрузить операцию равно, внутри метода все работает - массив получает новый размер и новые указатели. Но когда происходит return, то в обїекте остается только размер, а shared_ptr становится empty. Вроде бы, мне нужно использовать shared_from_this, но мне не нужно возвращать указатели на мой массив, а объект. Как это исправить?

```
class DynamicArr: public std::enable_shared_from_this<DynamicArr<T>>
{
    private:
        int Size;
        std::shared_ptr<T[]> arr;
    public:
        DynamicArr()
        {
            arr.reset(new T[1]);
            arr[0] = 0;
        }

        DynamicArr(int Size)
        {
            this->Size = Size;
            arr.reset(new T[Size]);
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; arr[i++] = Size-i);

        }
       DynamicArr(DynamicArr<T> &obj)
       {
          this->Size = obj.Size;
          arr = std::move(obj.arr);
       }
       ~DynamicArr() {
          arr.reset(new T[1]);
       }
       DynamicArr<T> operator= (const DynamicArr<T> &Arr2)
    {
        if (this != &Arr2)
        {
            this->Size = Arr2.Size;
            this->arr = Arr2.arr;
            return *this;
        }
        else
            return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Заявленная проблема не воспроизводится. Непонятно, зачем тут возвращать новый объект, может у вас проблема в конструкторе копирования?

Comment: Во-первых, зачем вам вручную перегружать `operator=`, если компилятор сам сгенерирует вам подходящий вариант? Во-вторых, [mcve] в студию.

Comment: Это не оператор равно, это  оператор присваивания.  Оператор равно обычно бозвращает bool... А ваш оператор должен возвращать этот же обьект(ссыльку на него), а не другой обьект, чтобы был желаемый результат. Возвратите   DynamicArr<T>&

Comment: Виноват, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: При таком объявлении класса реализовывать вообще ничего не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При таком объявлении класса реализовывать эти функции вообще не надо. Все конструкторы копирования и перемещения, операторы копирования и перемещения, а также деструктор будут правильно сгенерированы компилятором. Умные указатели в том числе для того и предназначены, чтобы в таком классе можно было пользоваться Правилом Ноля.

Не ясно, зачем вы написали конструктор копирования, который на самом деле разрушает (перемещает) исходный объект - из-за него ваш код и ведет себя странно.

Также, почему ваш оператор присваивания возвращает результат "по значению", вместо традиционного возвращения ссылки?

В данном случае можно было явно не писать и конструктор по умолчанию. Но раз вам зачем-то захотелось выделять там массив размера `1`, то так тому и быть. Однако вы забыли там инициализировать `Size`.

Причин для наследования от `std::enable_shared_from_this` в вашем классе тоже не видно.

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicArr
{
private:
  int Size;
  std::shared_ptr<T[]> arr;

public:
  DynamicArr() : Size(1), arr(new T[1]())
    {}

  DynamicArr(int Size) : Size(Size), arr(new T[Size])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; arr[i++] = Size-i);
  }
};
```

Также `arr[i++] = Size-i`. До C++17 это выражение вызывает неопределенное поведение. После С++17 правая часть оператора присваивания упорядочена перед левой. То есть ваш код заполняет массив значениями `{ Size, Size - 1, ..., 1 }`, а не `{ Size - 1, Size - 2, ..., 0 }`. Это именно то, что вы хотели? Это, кстати, не согласуется с тем, что делает конструктор по умолчанию (`arr[0] = 0;`).

(Что интересно, в GCC поведение действительно меняется в зависимости от `-std=c++17`)

Comment: По поводу move, то было требование от преподавателя обязательное реализовать конструктор копирования с уничтожением объекта откуда копируем. Перегрузка операторов также была требованием, хотя я и не знал что все это генерируется компилятором само. Неинициализированную переменную Size я тоже заметил, исправил почти сразу после публицакии вопроса здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Как я и предполагал, у вас неправильно реализован конструктор копирования - вместо копирования он выполняет перемещение указателя на массив из другого объекта. Соответственно при возвращении нового объекта из `operator =` будет происходить перемещение указателя на массив из текущего объекта в возвращаемый. Для исправления необходимо реализовать нормальный конструктор копирования и ничего не возвращать из `operator =`

```
DynamicArr(DynamicArr<T> const & obj)
:   Size{obj.Size}
:   arr{obj.arr}
{
    return;
}

void operator =(DynamicArr<T> const & obj)
{
    if(this != ::std::addressof(Arr2))
    {
        this->Size = obj.Size;
        this->arr = obj.arr;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Спасибо пользователю AR Hovseypan, теперь объект возвращается правильно.

```
DynamicArr<T>& operator= (const DynamicArr<T> &Arr2)
    {
        if (this != &Arr2)
        {
            this->Size = Arr2.Size;
            this->arr = Arr2.arr;
            return *this;
        }
        else
            return *this;
    }
```

Comment: Если вам пока не доступны комментарии, не стоит писать их в качестве ответа. Просто примите ответ в качестве верного.